# Custom Authentication for Admin in Django

Tags: django, django-admin

I'm writing a custom Django admin site for my vendors to log into.  This is to be separate from the regular Django admin site.  My question:  How do I override the admin authentication to also look from users from a vendor's table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you develop your own admin views, you should take a look into django´s decorators `@login_required` and `@user_passes_test`, and also the permission system.

So you can handle what your user are able to do and what not. Have a look into the Django Docs https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/default/

Hope this helps.